# How can I make the pager work with EntityFieldQuery if I am redirecting?

Tags: paging, database

I need to use pagers and understand them better to do so.

I have a module that produces custom forms gathering data for specific searches that then select that data using EntityFieldQuery, returning the nodes the user wants which I format as teasers and send back to an EmptyPage page. This works fine. When I add a pager, I only get the same records each time.  I have tried adding a pager to the EntityFieldQuery, but I see in step through debugging that the query only has the limit number of records.

Because of the redirect, it doesn't appear to come back through the module on refresh.
I have included some of my comment outs to illustrate some of what I've tried.

```
function ssti_search_digest_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
if (isset($_GET['page'])){
    $thispage = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $thispage = 0;        
}
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', 'weekly_digest')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->propertyOrderBy('created','DESC')
  ->fieldCondition('field_article_type','value', 'Digest','=')
//      ->pager(10,0)
  ->range(0, 50);
$keyword = trim($form_state['values']['keyword']);
if (strlen($keyword)>0){
    $query->fieldCondition('body','value', "%$keyword%", 'LIKE'); 
} 

$states = stateslist($form_state['values']['state']);
if (count($states)>0 && ! isset($states['0'])){
    $query->fieldCondition('field_states','value', (array) $states, 'IN'); 
} 

$tmp_q = $_GET['q']; // Store the current value of $_GET['q'].

$results = $query->execute();

$_GET['q'] = 'content/sstisearchresults/'; // Change the value of $_GET['q'] to the "correct" path you want the pager to link to.
if (isset($results['node'])) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = array('content/sstisearchresults',);
   $rows = $results['node'];
    $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($rows));
    $output = node_view_multiple($nodes,'teaser');
    $output['pager']['#markup'] = theme('pager'); 
} else {
    drupal_set_message('No results found');
}
$_GET['q'] = $tmp_q; // Return $_GET['q'] to the proper value.   
}


function ssti_search_digest_form($form, &$form_state){
$options = array('1' => t('Enabled'), '0' => t('Disabled'));
$form['search'] = array(
'#type' => 'fieldset',
'#title' => t(ssti_search_title_callback('digest')),
);  
$form['search']['keyword'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Keyword'),
'#size' => 30,
'#maxlength' => 64,
'#description' => t('Enter keywords to search for in title and text'),
);  
$form['search']['state'] = ssti_search_state_select_input();
$form['search']['start'] = ssti_search_date_select_input('start',strtotime('-1 months'));
$form['search']['finish'] = ssti_search_date_select_input('finish');
$form['search']['formtype'] = array(
'#value' => 'digest',
'#type' => 'hidden',
);
$form['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => t('Perform Search')); 

return $form;
}
```

And to cover the used modules, there are four forms that are presented separately in QuickTabs which is on an EmptyPage. Only one of the forms is submitted and processed and the output of the submit is sent to an EmptyPage. Everything works nicely except the pager, which displays correctly, but no matter which "page" you pick, you get the first page.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there are too many moving parts and the pieces needed to be separated.
What I finally did was to let the form(s) handled the gathering of information, pull the information from the form submit and send it to another page for displaying results, where the entity field query handles the paging on its own page.
The form submit code looks like this

```
function ssti_search_digest_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
form_state_values_clean($form_state);
$options['query']['searchtype']='digest';
foreach ($form_state['values'] as $retkey=>$retval){
    if (isset($retval) && ! is_null($retval)){
        if (is_string($retval) && ! strlen($retval)>0){continue;}
        $options['query'][$retkey]=$retval;
    }  
}
drupal_goto('content/sstisearchresults',$options);
}
```

sstisearchresults is set as a page_callback in the same module and is used by each of the four forms.  That code (simplified) is below.

```
function ssti_search_advanced_results() {
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
//choose between the content type based on sending form
switch($_GET['searchtype']){
    case 'supplement': 
        $searchtype='funding_supplement'; break;
    case 'resource': 
        $searchtype='resource_center'; break;
    case 'mep':
        $searchtype='meparticle'; break;
    case 'digest':
    default:
        $searchtype='weekly_digest'; break;
}    

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', $searchtype)
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->propertyOrderBy('created','DESC');

// set filters for passed parameters      

if (isset($_GET['keyword'])){
    $keyword = trim(check_plain(($_GET['keyword'])));
    $query->fieldCondition('body','value', "%$keyword%", 'LIKE'); 
}
if (isset($_GET['state'])){
    $states = $_GET['state'];
    if (count($states)>0 && ! isset($states['0'])){
        $query->fieldCondition('field_states','value', (array) $states, 'IN'); 
    }
}
// other parameter checks for all possible parameters
// setup pager    
$query->pager(10,0);

$results = $query->execute();
if (isset($results['node'])) {
   $rows = $results['node'];

    $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($rows));
    $output = node_view_multiple($nodes,'teaser');
    $output['pager']['#markup'] = theme('pager', $query->pager); 
    return $output;
} else {
    return t('No results found');
}
}
```

I had to remove the EmptyPage callback for the results page (conflict) and all is well.  The pager really does do what it is supposed to do, but it can get confused (or at least I can) depending on where the pager is being set up.  By separating the "gather parameters" from the "display results" pieces, it all came clear and now works.  In addition, all of the code for creating the query is in one spot for easy maintenance.